# React ESLint useState hook want to add carriage returns

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

I want to enforce linting in our React Native code base but one of the rules I disagree with has to do with formatting the useState hooks

When it comes to defining stateful properties with the `useState` hook, I prefer keeping the declaration on one line like so.

```js
const [responsibilities, setResponsibilities] = React.useState<ResponsibilitiesLookupModel[]>([]);
```

To me, a new line is a new statement and while you could go to a new indented line to communicate scope, the above is a single statement.

ESLint wants to reformat the line to the following

`` Replace `ResponsibilitiesLookupModel[]>([]);␍⏎␍⏎␍⏎··` with `␍⏎····ResponsibilitiesLookupModel[]␍⏎··>([]);`eslintprettier/prettier ``

so it looks like this

```js
  const [responsibilities, setResponsibilities] = React.useState<
    ResponsibilitiesLookupModel[]
  >([]);
```

Which gets hard to read when you have several declarations.

I've been digging through [react's linting docs](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/tree/master/docs/rules) and [prettier's options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) and I'm a bit lost as how I can disable this linting rule.

If this is the community's preferred way of authoring the useState hook, then I'm happy to adjust my style.

Comment: it may be because of the prettier `printWidth` setting which sets the max line length, try to set it to bigger number

Answer (score 0):

As @l-letovanec suggested, it was my printWidth that was missing.

The [print-width documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width) gives good comments on what to consider for this value.

```
module.exports = {
  bracketSpacing: false,
  bracketSameLine: true,
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'all',
  arrowParens: 'avoid',
  printWidth: 120
};
```